# My WordPress website is not displayed correctly

Tags: wordpress, windows-server

I am very new in WordPress and I am trying to create a simple website on company server. I am using the default theme.

Our IT already created a windows server 2016 for hosting the site.
I have installed WordPress via Web Platform Installer 5.0

The problem I am encountering is when I am trying to enter the site from my smartphone or any other external PC, it looks the CSS does not take effect.
If I am inspecting the elements (via F12) in the browser, I can see localhost instead of the IP of the site.

How can I replace the localhost to the website IP in my WordPress configuration?
Or let say where do I need to set the IP during the installation?

Update:
I performed a fresh installation of WordPress and just selected the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the CSS file path is hardcoded in *header.php* template.

**UPDATE:**

Other possibility would be that the WordPress URL and Site URL in **Settings > General** has localhost path in it.

Comment: Thanks but It is a fresh installation, no hardcoded path

Comment: What about WordPress URL and Site URL in Settings > General? Maybe one of them has localhost path in it.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. It works very fine. Please add this to your answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Updated an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you go to admin side **Settings** > **General** and change localhost URL to IP URL if the issue still persists then you check file permission.
After update site address and WordPress address, you need to fire some update query in MySQL so all localhost URL convert with IP.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl', 'newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl','newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl', 'newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl','newurl');
```

Or you may also install **WP Migrate DB Plugin** to change all Internal URL.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can rewrite permalinks with help `srdb`

search: `localhost/mysite`
replace: `www.mysite.com`

with `http://`

Before replace, do making backup your database

Comment: In which files?

Comment: @ehh In your database with help srdb tool